# How to obtain a specific text from a file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, awk, gnuplot

I generated a data file with the following format:

```
0.1
Analytic value = 340.347685734
Approximated value = 332.45634555
--
0.2
Analytic value = 340.936745872
Approximated value = 332.57893789
--
0.3
... and so on
```

I want to plot the analytic and approximate values in matplotlib/gnuplot against the input parameter (0.1, 0.2, etc). Usually, before generating the data file, I use to generate them with an awk script that puts the three values in three columns which is very easy to plot. However, here I accidentally generated the data file in a different format. How can I convert this text file to the following (maybe using regex or awk!):

```
0.1 340.347685734 332.45634555 
0.2 340.936745872 332.57893789
0.3 ... and so on
```

Or is there a way that I can plot the data without converting the format using gnuplot/matplotlib?

**EDIT:**
I have attempted to do it using python3. The following is my code:

```
file = open("myFile.dat",'r')
newFile = open("newFile.dat", 'a')
for i in range(4000):
  col1 = file.readline().split[-1]
  col2 = file.readline().split[-1]
  col3 = file.readline().split[-1]
  _ = file.readline().split[-1]
  line = col1 + " " + col2 + " " + col3
  newFile.write(line)
```

However, I was getting some error `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` which I didn't understand and I think this is a very inefficient code. That's why I asked in the SE. All the solutions presented so far work quite well. I marked the solution with `awk` as the accepted answer because it's simple and elegant. Also, I appreciate the solution that uses gnuplot only which also uncover a side of gnuplot for me.

Comment: Try this:
`awk '/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ {val = $0} /Analytic value =/ {split($0, a, " = "); analytic = a[3]} /Approximated value =/ {split($0, a, " = "); approx = a[3]; print val, analytic, approx}' your_file > output_file
`

Comment: Looks easy enough to do with Regex. What's your problem of coming up with a Regex that does it?

Comment: Even no Regex needed at all. 1. Replace `Analytic value = ` by nothing. 2. Replace `Approximated value = ` by nothing. 3. Replace `\n` by space. 4. Replace `--` by `\n`

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
0.1
Analytic value = 340.347685734
Approximated value = 332.45634555
--
0.2
Analytic value = 340.936745872
Approximated value = 332.57893789
--
```

then

```
awk '/^--$/{print "";next}{printf "%s ",$NF}' file.txt
```

doess output

```
0.1 340.347685734 332.45634555 
0.2 340.936745872 332.57893789
```

Explanation: for line being `--` just print newline and go to next one, for all others lines do output last field followed by space and not newline. If you want to know more about `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 2):

No Regex needed here. Just 4 simple replacements:

Two replacements for the unwanted text, one replacement to remove the line breaks and one replacement to insert a linebreak again.

```py
file = """0.1
Analytic value = 340.347685734
Approximated value = 332.45634555
--
0.2
Analytic value = 340.936745872
Approximated value = 332.57893789
--
0.3
... and so on
"""

file = file.replace("Analytic value = ","")
file = file.replace("Approximated value = ","")
file = file.replace("\n"," ")
file = file.replace("-- ","\n")
print(file)
```

Result:

```
0.1 340.347685734 332.45634555 
0.2 340.936745872 332.57893789 
0.3 ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem, and the choice will among others depend on the file size. Here is a simple solution for a case when you cannot load the whole file at once - you have to process it line by line,

```
raw_data_file = 'data.txt'
out_data_file = 'data_final.txt'

counter = 0
with open(raw_data_file, 'r') as fin, open(out_data_file, 'w') as fout:
    temp_line = []
    for line in fin:

        if counter == 0:
            # First column
            temp_line.append(line.strip())
            counter += 1
            continue
        elif counter == 1:
            # Analytic value column
            temp_line.append(line.strip().split()[-1])
            counter += 1
            continue
        elif counter == 2:
            # Approximate value column
            temp_line.append(line.strip().split()[-1])
            counter += 1
        elif counter == 3:
            # Skip the -- and reset the counter
            counter = 0
            continue

        # Write the rearranged data to file
        fout.write((' ').join(temp_line))
        fout.write('\n')
        temp_line = []
```

Note that this solution relies tightly on the structure of the file that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a way that I can plot the data without converting the format using gnuplot/matplotlib?

**Yes, there is!** Here is a platform-independent gnuplot-only solution. No need for external extra data preparation tools.

If you are plotting from a file, skip the `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` section and use `plot 'yourFile.dat' ...` .

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.6, March 2017)

```
### plot special data format
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.1
Analytic value = 340.347685734
Approximated value = 332.45634555
--
0.2
Analytic value = 340.936745872
Approximated value = 332.57893789
--
0.3
Analytic value = 341.936745872
Approximated value = 333.57893789
EOD

set datafile missing NaN
set key out
myFilter(colD,colF,valF) = strcol(colF) eq valF ? column(colD) : NaN

plot $Data u (valid(1)?x0=$1:x0):(myFilter(4,1,"Analytic"))     w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "analytic", \
        '' u (valid(1)?x0=$1:x0):(myFilter(4,1,"Approximated")) w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "approximated"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{n=(NR%4); val[n]=$NF} n==0{print val[1], val[2], val[3]}' file
0.1 340.347685734 332.45634555
0.2 340.936745872 332.57893789
```